# Auto approve FB members using a web app that's connected to "passwords" DB?

Tags: facebook-groups

What if I want to make a group only for specific students without manually accepting/refusing those who ask to join the group myself?

Assuming I've a database that has a number of passwords, and I've given one distinct password to every student, I want them to be automatically accepted if they ask to join and entered a correct password. I also do not want to allow them add/invite new members at all.

- Is this even possible using FB API at the current time?
- If so what topics/key_ideas/tags I must make a research about in
  order to create such a web app?
- If there is any other way around, I'd love to hear it.

I am not a programmer, I just had few programming courses.

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications! Please note that requests for app recommendations are off-topic here. Please focus on the problem you're trying to solve rather than the solution (a web application) that you think you need. Also, have a look at [How do I ask a question that may require recommending a web app?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3705/354)

Comment: Thank you for explaining, I removed asking for app recommendations, focused more on problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: no.

There is no way to accept group requests through Facebook Graph API.

You could accept passwords through group questions, and then comparing them to passwords in your database. Then you could make a js plugin that automatically clicks accept. But you would still need one admin to be online.

I would recommend studying Facebook for business, as it can be connected with custom domains (your login credentials).

Comment: Thank you for the explaining and your suggestions :)